# Unity Text Change not working

Tags: text, unity-game-engine, 2d

I have this simple platformer that has coins that you pick up and a canvas that shows the score and changes whenever you pick one up. This is my code:

```css
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour {

 Text text;
 
 private LVLMang levelManager;
 
 void Start () {
  text = GetComponent<Text> ();
  levelManager = FindObjectOfType<LVLMang> ();
 }
 
 void Update () {
  text.text = "" + levelManager.Score;
 }
}
```

It will add in the coins to the score, but it gives me so many errors that my game eventually crashes. The error is: 'NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object' and it highlights the text.text line. Please Help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure you have a Text component **on the object that has the script.** Your `GetComponent<Text> ();` call isn't finding a Text component.

Alternatively you can make `Text text;` public and hook it to the actual Text component you want to change by drag-dropping the Text-component object into the Script component's Text field.

Secondly, after updating the text.text value, call `text.SetAllDirty();` to get the change to take effect.

Comment: Thanks so much I am a fourteen year old working on my first platformer.  I am still getting the same error. I think it has to do with my coin and level manager script. Thanks so much!